# How to send a JSON Web Token in the request header, when making AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, token

I am having trouble getting the JSON Web Token that I received and stored in the Local Storage of my browser (after successfully logging in), into the Request Header of a POST request that I'm attempting afterwards.

The idea is that I'm trying to create a document, which can only be done by authorized (logged in) users, with a valid JSON Web Token in the local storage of their browser.

I created this Authorization middleware function to check if there is a token in the header of the request, but there seems to be none.

Do I need to add the token to the request header beforehand or is there something else wrong with my function?

```js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("user-token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided.");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
  }
};
```

Comment: local storage is only storage. you have to specify it on your reuqest.

Comment: I have just figured it out ... as a third argument to the POST request, I should add an options Object like so {headers: {'user-token: token}} , where token is defined like so:
const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token');